# When to use foreign keys in mysql

Tags: mysql, rdbms, foreign-key-relationship

I'm currently building a database and I'm not sure when to use foreign keys on the tables.
Most of the tables are for transaction, logging, and history.

Is there a general rule in which tables to put the foreign keys?
I have this table for the general details of a specific transaction, then another table for the specific details. Should I put a foreign key on the table for the specific details?

There's also this table used for storing user info and another for logging user activities. Should I also place a foreign key to the table that logs user activities?

Comment: Check this out:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868078/when-to-use-a-foreign-key-in-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a relation between two tables you should always enforce that using a foreign key constraint.

I prevents logically "corrupted" data (e.g. details for a transaction that doesn't actually exist) and - equally important - it *documents* your database model.

Comment: And it enforces indexing on both the primary and referencing columns.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: the primary key will always be indexed regardless of a FK constraint. But good point regarding the index on the fk columns.

Comment: I mean to say that MySQL will complain with err150 if the referenced column is _not already_ indexed when the FK constraint is created. In other words, if it was not a PK on the referenced table, so it must have _some_ index for the constraint to be created in the first place.